# Upload the document to Google docs from URL using google document API

Tags: google-docs-api

I have a URL of a document hosted at a provider and want to upload it to Google docs using the Google Docs API. Is there any way to achieve it? I have been searching for a while .

Comment: Have you figured it out ?

Comment: @OnlyHope : Nope , it seems to be a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me. It will return with a File Object.

```
DocsList.createFile(UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileURL);
```